# Debian change dist-package path

Tags: python-3.x, debian, apt, debian-packaging

I'm currently using Debian GNU/Linux bookworm, but I'm struggling with python3 package updates.
In fact, it uses :
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` to check for packages installed for system software and this is not what i want. This directory contains python3.9 packages, and it later raises compatibility uses

**I want to use this directory instead:**
`/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/`
That exists in my computer with the software in the version that i want but it doesn't works. I've tried the

```bash
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.10
PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/me/.local/lib/
export PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
export PYTHON_LIBRARY
```

commands, but it did not work.
My py sys.path contains :

```py
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/me/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I would really appreciate some help on this one :,(

I even tried to reinstall python and reboot (which caused GNOME to crash), but it stils uses python3.9 dist package path, i don't know how to get rid of it, or even how to update it !

Comment: How exactly did you install and configure Python 3.10?

Comment: It has been installed when upgrading to the unstable version of debian

Comment: That cannot be true; it would not live in `/usr/local` then.

Comment: So this means that my system uses python3.9 ? (thanks for your help btw °^°)

Comment: The problem is that when i add `print(sys.version)` in _core_ files such as the dist_package repo, it always shows python3.10, so i assumed it was the one used everywhere

Comment: It's quite possible that you have a reproducible problem but your question does not currently contain enough information to reproduce it. If indeed the dist-upgrade left you with incompatible packages, that's a bug.

Comment: The `/usr/local` path might merely be a tangential misunderstanding, or an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). That directory should not be used by the system `pip`.